# Some imports are missing in ng2-charts@3.0.8

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have recently update `chart.js` from `2.9.4` to `3.6.0` and `ng2-chart` from `2.4.3` to `3.0.8`.

I have followed the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html) from chart.js to migrate to v3.X

I've update my imported module from `import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';`  to `import { NgChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts';`  as provided in the ng2-charts [documentation](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts#installation)

But since i've update thoses package some imports seems to be missing.

For example before updating i've used to import `import { Label, PluginServiceGlobalRegistrationAndOptions } from 'ng2-charts';` but since the update those import are missing from ng2-charts package, and I havn't found any information about this in ng2charts website / github or chart.js.

Does anyone face the same issue concerning missing import due to the migration ?

NB: I'm using `angular@13.1.4`

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

They took away the labels and color and some schemas i guess we have to declare those in component.ts...
eg:
labels:[]
and then declare them to your own

I dont know how to post the code but here is a link to the new charts in github

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts.git

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31245958)

Comment: Ok bro I will try to be more descriptive from now on ....!

Answer (score 1):

See this thread on ng2-charts
https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/1386

`Label` is just `string[]` so you can replace it like that. Regarding `PluginServiceGlobalRegistrationAndOptions` I just don't know - I suppose you need to fallback to `any`.